# YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player in ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, android-viewpager, android-framelayout

Am using AutoPlay YouTube video fragment inside ViewPager.

I got error like,

YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player.

I have googled it and I got this link,
[Show Youtube video within viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086897/show-youtube-video-within-viewpager)

After implementing this method setUserVisibleHint(),
Still video paused... Getting same error. Please anybody help me with this.

```
   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.RelativeLayout{216081f V........ ........ 1080,0-2160,1536 #7f0900cf app:id/relativeNews}

I have used viewpager and above framelayout everything inside relative layout

I tried removing every parent layouts and just put above framelayout as parent.
Again am getting

The YouTubePlayerView is obscured by android.widget.FrameLayout{216081f V........ ........ 1080,0-2160,1536 #7f0900cf app:id/youtube_fragment}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is only with your layout. Youtube player does not permit over any layout.

Make sure remove all layout over it and try again.

Comment: But I need to put text below the player how is it possible? can you please give me some code

Comment: @syedjibharat Have you use this "com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView" for play video?

Comment: yes but still getting same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570169/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-youtube-player-youtubeplayerview-in-lis

Comment: Try with this, may be it will help you
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="190dp" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgDropDown"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />                
</LinearLayout>